# Making own 'tar' program... how to create files/directories with C code?

Tags: c, unix

My own tar file can currently use the 'c' and 't' commands correctly (creating he archive, reading the archive), but I'm completely unaware of how to implement 'x' (extracting the archive).

Using C code, how can I recreate a directory / file? I know I can successfully read what is in my .tar file, I'm just not sure of the C function that is used to create directores / files.

NOTE: I've asked multiple people, they couldn't help me. Googled the problem for an hour, but the question is vague enough that I got about 10000 websites answering a different problem.

Comment: `mkdir()` to create a directory. If you can create the archive then you already know how to create a file.

Comment: You mean like `mkdir`, `open` or `creat`?

Comment: Check out this question for creating files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395465/create-a-file-in-linux-using-c

Answer (score 1):

Use fopen to create a file (and write to it); use mkdir to create a directory.

Answer (score 0):

on unix systems ,you'd use [mkdir()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/mkdir.html)